# regex comparison with conditional operators

Tags: java, regex

Is that possible to compare the strings in regex with conditional operators(not in split type)

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. At least give some example inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: I have Json like this, i need to compare value of first object with the oeprator , similarly for second object, if both are satisfied then i need to use conditional operator to match two objects, [{"operator":"<=","value":10,"conditionalOperator":"And"},{"operator":"=>","value":"25","conditionalOperator":null}]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type of regex,

```
.*?(word1 word2 word3).*?\/\/\/.*?(?(1)\1)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/142),,, in which the `sub_string(\1, "word1 word2 word3")` is checked if it is included in `former string`, and attempts to match the sub-string in the `latter string`.

It's the `///` which used to `sectionalize`(or `delimit`) to the former and latter strings.